# Need a good reference for Google Generic Widget class

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to see all the methods that I can use on a Generic Widget in Google Apps script, but I can't find anything unsubstantial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the link you are looking for.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_widget

Keep in mind that Apps script is built upon Google's Web Toolkit (used in the App engine service). You can look at that to have better understanding of how things work.
However, Apps Script is another service and as you will quickly see, everytime a widget gets implemented in Apps Script it has less property's and methods.

Lastly, you could always post a feature request on http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/. If other people 'star' it enough, google might implement your request. Its a fairly honest system and they do prioritise their efforts based upon it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to see all **public** methods. The following code does this

```
function test() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  // Method 1
  var functions1 = Object.keys(app);
  // Method 2
  var functions2 = [];
  for (var f in app) {
    functions2.push(f);
  }
}
```

The arrays `functions1` and `functions2` contain the same list of public functions of any object, also any generic widget.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this?:
  http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html

Comment: I have gone through all the methods, but is does not include any of the Google app specific ones like .get id or . set tag

Comment: I dont know much about the subject so this is too in depth for me but it might help you: http://netoearth.com/book/ProgrammingGoogleAppEngine.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will have some use, but if you want to save yourself some time here is the list of all the methods you can use on a Generic Widget in Google. Feel Free to fill in some info on any methods.

```
addKeyPressHandler, 
setReadOnly, 
setDialogTitle, 
setStylePrimaryName,
 addMouseDownHandler, 
addBeforeSelectionHandler, 
addSubmitCompleteHandler, 
setModal, setGlassEnabled, 
setAutoHideEnabled, 
setWidgetPosition, 
setPreviewingAllNativeEvents,
 addSouth, 
addKeyUpHandler, 
setCellHorizontalAlignment, 
addMouseMoveHandler, 
setTabEnabled,
 setWidgetLeftRight,
 removeRow, 
setLimit, 
addStyleName, 
getId, 
showDatePicker, 
setWidgetBottomHeight, 
setDefaultValue, 
setCommand,
 setPopupPositionAndShow, 
setWidgetLeftWidth, 
setWidgetHorizontalPosition, 
setStyleName, 
setAlwaysShowScrollBars, 
addMouseWheelHandler, 
setHref, 
addTab, 
addSubmitHandler, 
setItemSelected, 
hideDatePicker, 
remove, 
addLoadHandler, 
setItemText, 
setVisibleRect, 
addItem, 
setLayoutData, 
showDocsPicker, 
clear, 
insertRow, 
setFormValue, 
setUrl, 
setWidgetVerticalPosition, 
addEast, 
setAction, 
removeCell,
setCellHeight, 
setId, 
addWest, 
addClickHandler,
 setCharacterWidth, 
setCaptionText, 
setTabText, 
setCellWidth, 
addScrollHandler, 
setScrollPosition, 
setVisible,
 setUserObject, 
setVisibleLines, 
setMaxLength,
 setSelectionRange,
 setMethod,
 setSelectedIndex,
 addMouseOverHandler,
addNorth, 
setWordWrap,
 removeItem,
 addCloseHandler,
 setStyleAttribute,
 setCellPadding,
 insertCell, 
addChangeHandler,
 setText,
 setContentWidget, 
setGlassStyleName, 
resize, 
setTarget,
 setAccessKey, 
addAutoHidePartner, 
setTag, 
setInitialView, 
setSelectedItem,
 addView,
 setBorderWidth, 
setSubMenu,
 removeCells, 
setCurrentMonth, 
setTextAlignment, 
setID, 
addFocusHandler, 
setVerticalAlignment, 
setPixelSize,
 setTabIndex, 
selectTab, 
setResource, 
setWidgetTopHeight,
 setFormat, 
setStackText, 
setVisibleLength, 
addSeparator,
 setTitle, 
setVisibleItemCount, 
setHeight, 
setSpacing,
 addMouseOutHandler,
 toString, 
addMouseUpHandler,
 setPopupPosition,
 setName, 
setWidgetTopBottom, 
setHorizontalScrollPosition, 
setTargetHistoryToken,
setCellSpacing, 
setPopupStyleName, 
getTag, 
addCell, 
addStyleDependentName, 
setDown, 
addInitializeHandler, 
setWidget, 
setChecked,
 add, 
addKeyDownHandler, 
setCursorPos, 
getType, 
setEnabled, 
setState, 
setWidth, 
setUrlAndVisibleRect, 
setFocus, 
setDirection, 
addErrorHandler,
 addValueChangeHandler, 
setSize, 
addSelectionHandler, 
addBlurHandler,
 setMultiSelectEnabled,
 setValue, 
setHorizontalAlignment, 
setEncoding,
 setAutoSelectEnabled,
 setAutoOpen,
 setWidgetMinSize,
 setCellVerticalAlignment,
 setWidgetRightWidth,
 setAnimationEnabled,
 setSelected, 
setHTML
```